# .ajax Delete method not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having issues with my DELETE request. It keeps returning 404 not found when the method is there. I've tried POST method and it worked so I don't know what is going on. Below is the jQuery for my request method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');

        } else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

        }
    });
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var person = new Object();
        var dbname = document.getElementById('Label2');
        //alert(dbname.innerHTML);//db table name
        var data = table.cell('.selected', 0).data()
        //alert(String(data));//ID
        person.name = dbname.innerHTML;
        person.surname = String(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://172.20.129.139/fa/summary.aspx/relic",
            type: "delete",
            async: false,
            data: person,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Submitted!');
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('Oh no :(');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Below is the codes for summary.aspx/relic

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string relic(person data)
    {
        dynamic result = data;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["hey"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        string query = "delete from "+data.name+" where ID= '"+data.surname+"'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: does your server accept delete requests?

Comment: how do you check that?

Comment: check you server configuration

Comment: post your server side code for handling this request

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should really remove `async: false`. It's incredibly bad practice

Comment: I dont understand(i am very new to this). I am using iis. How do i check the server configuration of it.

Comment: It's not IIS you need to check, but the code of your `summary.aspx/relic` endpoint

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: @Wasd another big problem is that your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. A malicious user could send data which could steal, corrupt or destroy your data. Please learn to use parameterised queries - almost all the examples online of using the ADO.NET libraries (which you use) demonstrate the proper use of this. It will greatly reduce the risk of injection attacks (and syntax errors, incidentally, as well). And also, Rory is right, `async:false` produces terrible user experience and is deprecated by some browsers - at some time in future it will not work at all.

Comment: Replace the url to url:url: "http://172.20.129.139/fa/summary.aspx/relic?person =person ", & data to like data:{}

Comment: @ADyson ok got it! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It still doesnt work :(

Comment: I have added the verb delete into my handler already but to no avail